# Synchronous request/response processing on a web server

Tags: java, rest, http, webserver, server

I found many resources on synchronous and asynchronous behavior of RESTful clients, but not much about controlling the server bahaviour. As far as I know many servers, like Glassfish, Jetty support asynchronous request/response processing. My question is, is there a way to achieve synchronous request/response processing on the server side by configuration/annotation means?

Comment: Synchronous is the default.

Comment: @Lutz Horn Can you point me to some documentation?